# How do i create a hamburger menu using just bootstrap, no css?

Tags: bootstrap-5

I would like to create a hamburger menu for the menu items U.S, World, etc as shown below. Have tried various methods shown on bootstrap docs and they keep messing up my codes. Could someone please take a look at my code and see how i can achieve that?
This a screenshot example of the menu items as I want them displayed on the browser in smaller screens;
[image][1]
Here is my code on the menu items;

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-light">
        <div>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link fw-bolder text-black  border-end " aria-current="page" href="#">U.S</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link fw-bolder text-black border-end" aria-current="page" href="#">World</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link fw-bolder text-black border-end" aria-current="page" href="#">Science</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link fw-bolder text-black  border-end" aria-current="page" href="#">Cultures</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link fw-bolder text-black  border-end" aria-current="page" href="#">Autos</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link fw-bolder text-black border-end" aria-current="page" href="#">Rankings</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link fw-bolder text-black border-end" aria-current="page" href="#">Heealth</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link fw-bolder text-black border-end" aria-current="page" href="#">Life</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link fw-bolder text-black border-end" aria-current="page" href="#">Opinions</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link fw-bolder text-black border-end" aria-current="page" href="#">Experts</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link fw-bolder text-black border-end" aria-current="page" href="#">Education</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link fw-bolder text-black border-end" aria-current="page" href="#">Podcasts</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link fw-bolder text-black border-end" aria-current="page" href="#">Vintage</a>
              </li>
              <form class="d-flex" role="search">
                <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
            </div>
```

I also uploaded the entire code on github for those who need to have a look https://github.com/maureenblack/Newsweek

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the toggler icon is not visible because of its color. For the colors selected, you can add the **navbar-light** class to the **nav** element for the icon to show. See below. (and also be sure to include bootstrap script and stylesheet).

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
  integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-light navbar-light">
  <div>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav"
      aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link fw-bolder text-black  border-end " aria-current="page" href="#">U.S</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link fw-bolder text-black border-end" aria-current="page" href="#">World</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link fw-bolder text-black border-end" aria-current="page" href="#">Science</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link fw-bolder text-black  border-end" aria-current="page" href="#">Cultures</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link fw-bolder text-black  border-end" aria-current="page" href="#">Autos</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link fw-bolder text-black border-end" aria-current="page" href="#">Rankings</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link fw-bolder text-black border-end" aria-current="page" href="#">Heealth</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link fw-bolder text-black border-end" aria-current="page" href="#">Life</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link fw-bolder text-black border-end" aria-current="page" href="#">Opinions</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link fw-bolder text-black border-end" aria-current="page" href="#">Experts</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link fw-bolder text-black border-end" aria-current="page" href="#">Education</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link fw-bolder text-black border-end" aria-current="page" href="#">Podcasts</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link fw-bolder text-black border-end" aria-current="page" href="#">Vintage</a>
        </li>
        <form class="d-flex" role="search">
          <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```